# I am struggling to create a dictionary from a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a CSV file, called 'scores.csv'. The format of it is like so.
Username,Score

I've tried using the code below to put the Username as a key in a dictionary, and the subsequent Score as the value, however when this code is run, and I print the dictionary, it will only print 3 random Username:Score combinations every time.

```
import csv
import operator

reader = csv.reader(open("scores.csv"))
d={}
for row in reader:
    d[row[0]]=row[1:]

print(d)
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Try printing what is row[0] and what is row[1:].

Comment: @rnso I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @rnso sorry, I'm doing this at GCSE level.

Comment: Insert in loop `print(row[1:])` and see output.

Answer (score 0):

Using Pandas (not header in scores.csv):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("scores.csv", header=None)
dicc= pd.Series(df[1].values,index=df[0]).to_dict()
```

Using csv.reader, for my works, I recommend use ".strip()":

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open("scores.csv"))
d={}
for row in reader:
    d[row[0].strip()]=row[1].strip()

print(d)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help.

The output for the csv.reader part you helpfully wrote outputs this:
{'15randallhar': '12', '15blackkyl': '8', '15seawardlia': '0'}
Despite there being more keys:values in the CSV file. The CSV file has 7 key:value combinations.